# Scraping of fortune 500 company list for 2021 using Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and currently learning the language. For educational purpose I was trying to web scrape the fortune 500 list of companies from https://fortune.com/fortune500/2021/search for my analysis

I am kind of stuck. I was able to get so far below but the result is empty. Can some one help? Appreciate it

I am using ipynb notebooks in google colab for this exercise. I am trying to print the content of the table in a csv file.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://fortune.com/fortune500/2021/search"

try:
   page = urlopen(url)
except:
   print("Error opening the URL")

# create a BeautifulSoup object for parsing
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

table_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'rt-tbody'})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't scrape the site using `beautifulsoup`. The table is rendered using `JavaScript` so the table isn't present in the source html of the page. If you want to scrape you can use [pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer), to first render the page and get the html.

However, the data can be found on this url
https://content.fortune.com/wp-json/irving/v1/data/franchise-search-results?list_id=3040727&token=Zm9ydHVuZTpCcHNyZmtNZCN5SndjWkkhNHFqMndEOTM=.
It contains a token so, the url may not work after some time but you can still open up DevTools and look up the url on the `Network Tab` filtered by `XHR`.

Comment: If they use BeautifulSoup alongside Selenium instead of urllib, they can scrape it. And the token with the Selenium webdriver will be no issue either. The webdriver will automatically obtain a new one on the next page load just as a normal browser will.