# Scraping of fortune 500 company list for 2023 using Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to locate the url that sends the data to a webpage.

I tried scrapping https://fortune.com/ranking/global500/2023/search/ using Bs4 but found that because the table isn't populated using data in the html, Bs4 would not suffice (courtesy of this previous post ([Scraping of fortune 500 company list for 2021 using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67889928/scraping-of-fortune-500-company-list-for-2021-using-python)).

I tried looking for the data url using the devtools and had no luck. Instructions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the page is stored in `<script>` element in Json form. To load it to pandas dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import json

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://fortune.com/ranking/global500/2023/search/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__")
data = json.loads(data.text)

items = data["props"]["pageProps"]["franchiseList"]["items"]

df = pd.DataFrame([{**i.pop("data"), **i} for i in items])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Newcomer to the Global 500 Dropped in Rank Gained in Rank                         Sector                                        Industry Country / Territory         Headquarters City    Headquarters State Profitable World's Most Admired Companies Female CEO Growth in Jobs Change the World Fastest Growing Companies Fortune 500 Best Companies Non-U.S. Companies Rank Revenues ($M) Revenue Percent Change Profits ($M) Profits Percent Change Assets ($M)  Employees Change in Rank Years on Global 500 List                                      name  rank                                                         slug
0                           no              no             no                      Retailing                           General Merchandisers                U.S.               Bentonville              Arkansas        yes                            yes         no             no              yes                        no         yes             no                 no    1      $611,289                   6.7%      $11,680                 -14.6%    $243,197  2,100,000                                      29                                   Walmart     1                                   /company/walmart/global500
1                           no              no            yes                         Energy                    Mining, Crude-Oil Production        Saudi Arabia                   Dhahran                              yes                             no         no            yes               no                        no          no             no                yes    2      $603,651                  50.8%     $159,069                    51%    $663,541     70,496              4                        5                              Saudi Aramco     2                              /company/saudi-aramco/global500
2                           no              no             no                         Energy                                       Utilities               China                   Beijing                              yes                             no         no             no               no                        no          no             no                yes    3      $530,009                  15.1%       $8,192                  14.8%    $710,763    870,287                                      23                                State Grid     3                                /company/state-grid/global500
3                           no             yes             no                      Retailing                 Internet Services and Retailing                U.S.                   Seattle            Washington         no                            yes         no             no               no                        no         yes             no                 no    4      $513,983                   9.4%      $-2,722                -108.2%    $462,675  1,541,000             -2                       15                                    Amazon     4                                /company/amazon-com/global500
4                           no             yes             no                         Energy                              Petroleum Refining               China                   Beijing                              yes                             no         no             no               no                        no          no             no                yes    5      $483,019                  17.3%      $21,080                 118.7%    $637,223  1,087,049             -1                       23                  China National Petroleum     5                  /company/china-national-petroleum/global500
5                           no             yes             no                         Energy                              Petroleum Refining               China                   Beijing                              yes                             no         no             no               no                        no          no             no                yes    6      $471,154                  17.4%       $9,657                  16.1%    $368,751    527,487             -1                       25                             Sinopec Group     6                             /company/sinopec-group/global500

...
```